# Javascript AJAX + JQuery posts empty data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I am new to web programming and am struggling with a basic task. I am trying to do a simple POST from my frontend to my backend and with it send data in the form of a JSON object. I specifically do not want to embed my javascript code in my HTML file. Please note that all the code shown is all the code used for this POST purpose, so if it looks like I am missing something I most likely am. My frontend JS code is as follows:

```
/**/
function Test_Button_Pressed() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {Name: "Rikus", Value: 123},
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err); //just use the err here
        }
    });
}

/**/
function Activation_Button_Pressed(Button_ID) {}

/**/
function Button_Pressed(Button_ID) {}
```

The following is logged in the Chrome console when the backend response was made:

```
Error: [object Object]
```

The backend code is as follows:

```
const Api = require("./Api");

var Communication = {};

/**/
Communication.SetUp = function (PanelApp, DataApp) {
    PanelApp.post('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req);
        console.log(req.params);
        console.log(req.body);
        res.send("Done");
    });
};

module.exports = Communication;
```

Bothe the

```
console.log(req.body)
```

and

```
console.log(req.params)
```

returns: {}

so from what I can see my routing is correct, it's only my data sending that does not work. Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Get rid of `contentType: "application/json",`. `$.ajax` sends URL-encoded content, not JSON.

Comment: And change `console.log("Error: " + err)` to `console.log("Error: ", err)` since `err` is an object, not a string.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, removing the ``` contentType :  "application/json"``` worked, I am now receiving the data at the backend. However the ```res.send("Done")``` still isn't working because I am still receiving the error message.

Comment: You need to use `res.json()`, since you have `dataType: "json"`.

Comment: Thank you Barmar, everything works 100% now.

Answer (score 0):

After some help the working code is as follows:

Frontend:

```
/**/
function Test_Button_Pressed() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/test",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {Name: "Rikus", Value: 123},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("Error: ", err); //just use the err here
        }
    });
}

/**/
function Activation_Button_Pressed(Button_ID) {}

/**/
function Button_Pressed(Button_ID) {}
```

Backend

```
const Api = require("./Api");

var Communication = {};

/**/
Communication.SetUp = function (PanelApp, DataApp) {
    PanelApp.post('/test', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.body.Name);
        console.log(req.body.Value);
        res.json("Done");
    });
};

module.exports = Communication;
```